# How to lookup mib-table in pysnmp?

Tags: python, snmp, mib, pysnmp

When I use snmpwalk on a OID ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4), i get the following result as:

```
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memIndex.0 = INTEGER: 0

UCD-SNMP-MIB::memErrorName.0 = STRING: swap

UCD-SNMP-MIB::memMinimumSwap.0 = INTEGER: 16000 kB
```

But, when i use the pysnmp module to query the same OID, i get the results as:

```
(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.1.0), Integer(0))

(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.2.0), OctetString('swap'))

(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.12.0), Integer(16000))
```

I have put the pysnmp_mibs in os.environ and the code i'm using is:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, error

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, \
             varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd (
cmdgen.CommunityData('test-agent', 'public'),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget ( (localhost, 161) ),
('1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4')
)

if errorIndication:
    log.warn(errorIndication)
    return
else:
    if errorStatus:
        log.warn( '%s at %s\n' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint (),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int (errorIndex) - 1] or '?'
            ))
        return
    else:
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for oid, val in varBindTableRow:
                    (symName, modName), indices = cmdgen.mibvar.oidToMibName(
                        cmdGen.mibViewController, oid
                        )
                    val = cmdgen.mibvar.cloneFromMibValue(
                                  cmdGen.mibViewController, modName, symName, val
                          )
            print varBindTableRow
```

My question is why is snmpwalk and pysnmp results different, and what should i do to get the results same as snmpwalk using pysnmp module?

---

***Edited***:

i tried the code,but on querying 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1
i get the following error

```
NoSuchObjectError: NoSuchObjectError({'str': 'No MIB info for    (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2021, 4, 1, 0) (closest parent (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1))'})
```

I have loaded the IP-MIB module as:

```
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder() 
mibPath = mibBuilder.getMibSources()+(builder.DirMibSource(path_to_mib_dir),)
mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibPath)
mibBuilder.loadModules('IP-MIB')
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)
```

What i am confused is how do i use this ***mibView*** in

```
(symName,modName),indices=cmdgen.mibvar.oidToMibName(cmdGen.mibViewController, oid)
val=cmdgen.mibvar.cloneFromMibValue(cmdGen.mibViewController,modName, symName, val)
```

should the **cmdGen.mibViewController** be replaced with the **mibView**?

but it works on OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3:
and i get the result as expected as:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = 27
```

Comment: You seem to load IP-MIB into *another* instance of the MIB tree, not the same you use for OID resolution. Your IP-MIB loading code might work if you use mibBuilder = cmdGen.mibViewController.mibBuilder

Comment: You also refer to 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.1.0 which is defined in UCD-SNMP-MIB. Since pysnmp-mibs does not [yet] contain that MIB, you'd have to compile it into python module with pysnmp/tools/build-pysnmp-mib script. Once it's loaded, your OID resolution might work.

Comment: Thanks. mibBuilder = cmdGen.mibViewController.mibBuilder worked.
But i get a :
`./build-pysnmp-mib ~/Desktop/src/UCD-SNMP-MIB.mib 
    Empty input
    smidump -k -f python /Users/furion/Desktop/src/UCD-SNMP-MIB.mib |     ./libsmi2pysnmp fails
    make sure you are using libsmi version > 0.4.5 (or svn)`
error while trying to compile the UCD-SNMP-MIB using pysnmp/tools/build-pysnmp-mib script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing:

```
print '%s::%s.%s = %s' % (
                    modName, symName,
                    '.'.join(map(lambda v: v.prettyPrint(), indices),
                    val.prettyPrint()
                    )
```

instead of

```
print varBindTableRow
```

Also make sure you load appropriate MIB.

Comment: I tried the above code as well, but i am getting errors.
Please look at my question, i have edited it which contains the details of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the results are the same !

If your problem is about 16000 versus 16000 KB, you must know that SNMP does not return the unit. SNMP V2 MIB allow just a place to give information about it, so SNMPWALK(as a client) is using it, not pysnmp.

Comment: By same results, i mean how to make my pysnmp display result as 
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memIndex.0 = INTEGER: 0,
instead of,
(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.1.0), Integer(0))
Yes they are the same results, but the previous one is more readable, i just want to make the output readable.